# Offline notification with nuxt/pwa

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

I am currently looking through the options of creating an offline indication for the nuxt/pwa project. Since this moment, app is running perfectly offline, but what I want to do is to push a small notification when there is no connection saying something simple such as "you are currently offline". 
I can see that there are multiple ways of doing this such as writing the event listener directly in the default layout, but my question is which one is the most suitable and reliable for the nuxt setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to write your own event listener, as this seems to be taken care of by the nuxt already. The network status seems to be accessible via `$nuxt` helper's `isOnline` and `isOffline` properties. Check out this example:

https://nuxtjs.org/api/$nuxt/

I have not worked with this yet, but I think it might be what you are looking for.

Note: Make sure to copy the whole link, as stackoverflow cuts it off at `/$nuxt`.

Comment: Lovely answer! Thank you for the help

Comment: I was glad to help! :0)